# In Spring 5, how do I customize a form validation error message?

Tags: spring, forms, validation, spring-mvc, error-handling

I'm using Spring 5.1.  I want to write a validator for a form I'm submitting and I would like to customize one of the error messages that comes back.  I have the error message stored in a properties file ...

```
already.taken.registration.username=There is already an account created with the username {0}.  Did you forget your password?
```

Note the "{0}" for where I would like to insert the invalid username the user has entered.  So in my validator I have

```
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
...
public class RegistrationFormValidator implements Validator
{

    ...
    @Override
    public void validate(final Object target, final Errors errors)
    {
        final RegistrationForm regForm = (RegistrationForm) target;

        if (regForm != null && 
                   !StringUtils.isEmpty(regForm.getEmail()) &&
                   userWithEmail(regForm.getEmail()) ) {
            errors.rejectValue("email", "already.taken.registration.username", regForm.getEmail());
        }   // if
```

However, when the specific branch is run, the {0} isn't getting populated, despite the fact I've verified that "regForm.getEmail()" is non-empty.  I see this printed to my JSP page

```
There is already an account created with the username {0}. Did you forget your password?
```

What's the correct way to fill in the error message with custom data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
errors.rejectValue("email", "already.taken.registration.username", regForm.getEmail());
```

This will actually call the method

```
void rejectValue(@Nullable
             java.lang.String field,
             java.lang.String errorCode,
             java.lang.String defaultMessage)
```

What you need is to add an array of objects with the arguments:

```
void rejectValue(@Nullable
             java.lang.String field,
             java.lang.String errorCode,
             @Nullable
             java.lang.Object[] errorArgs,
             @Nullable
             java.lang.String defaultMessage)
```

Your call will be something like this :

```
errors.rejectValue("email", "already.taken.registration.username", new Object[] {regForm.getEmail()}, null);
```